# How to send an email which exactly looks in the outlook express how i see in my web browser?

Tags: .net, html, email, outlook, newsletter

In my web browser this shows correctly. But when i send it to Gmail or Outlook it does not show correctly nor it show in the center alignment layouts. (many other newsletter i receive they fit it exactly in the center).

HTML to send:

```
<form target="theFrame" >
<DIV class=contents style="width:527px;">
   <DIV class=contents_body style="padding-left:150px;">
          Why you are not padding, in Outlook? And showing full texts in 100% width?
   </DIV>
</DIV>
</form>
<iframe name='theFrame'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because email clients are based on older versions of html and will not render the same as a browser.

If you have a look at online services such as email on acid or litmus you can test how your email will look in various email clients prior to sending.

Keep your email template basic and favour old style table layouts.

How about a spacer image?

```
<DIV class=contents style="width:527px;">
   <img src="yoururl/img/spacer.gif" width="150px" align="left" />
   <DIV class=contents_body style="padding-left:150px;">
          Why you are not padding, in Outlook? And showing full texts in 100% width?
   </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: please see my above updates. In Gmail it shows exactly in the center. But still not in the outlook.